# Securely storing an access token

Tags: security, encryption, oauth, access-token

What security measures should I put in place to ensure that, were my database to be compromised, long-life access tokens could not be stolen?

A long-life access token is as good as a username and password for a particular service, but from talking to others it seems most (myself included) store access tokens in plain text. This seems to be to be just as bad as storing a password in plain text. Obviously one cannot salt & hash the token.

Ideally I'd want to encrypt them, but I'm unsure of the best way to do this, especially on an open source project.

I imagine the answer to this question is similar to one on storing payment info and PCI compliance, but I'd also ask why there isn't more discussion of this? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: What do you mean "especially on an open source project"? What are you thinking that makes your decision to go with a specific type of encryption scheme different because your project is not closed source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you just want to verify a token provided by others? If so, treat it as you would a password.  Use a byte derivation algorithm like [Password Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (also described in [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)) with 10,000 iterations and store the first 20 bytes or so. When the token is received. It is not practically reversible.

Do you want to present the token to others for authentication? If so, this is a challenge because, if your application can decrypt or otherwise get access to the token, so can an attacker. Think Shannon's Maxim, the attacker knows the system, especially for an open source project.

In this case, the best approach is to encrypt the tokens with a strong algorithm (e.g. AES256), generate keys using a strong cryptographic standard random number generator and store the key(s) securely in a different location to the data, such as in a permission protected file outside the database in the example above. The latter means that SQL injection attacks will not reveal the keys.

Comment: Thanks – I'm more referring to the latter of your use cases, where I need to be able to use the token at a later time when the user is not present.

Comment: @akton but why treat the token like a password? (plain text) passwords are information we don't want an attacker to get b/c he/she could try and use it to login into a different service with the same pwd. but a token is only valid for your own service - so if the attacker got his/her hands on the token/db he/she could do more harm than just use the token to login to your account ... what am I not seeing?

Comment: Assuming the question is correct, the token is a per-user, long-lived piece of evidence that can authenticate a user. In other words, it is a password.

Comment: Would the answer be different for a short lived access token?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka It depends on what "short lived" means. If it is used within a single request or action the need for protection is much less. If you store it between requests or actions you should protect it as directed above.