# Social networks as login for RESTful web service

Tags: web-services, security, rest, restful-authentication

I am working on a RESTful web service implementation and wanted to provide security for my RESTful web service, but I dont want to take the pain of registering user and maintaining and asking new customers to create another account.

I was planning to piggy back on social network's authentication like facebook/twitter/google+. I read lot of documents online and lot of questions here in stackoverflow, but I am still a bit off understanding how all this works.

This is what I understood from all my reading

1. register a app in facebook/twitter/google and get app ID
2. use connect button in my web app and user connects and we get back access token from the social network site that says that user authenticated my app.

My question is, how is this secure ? If someone gets access to the access token, they can also act as the authenticated user. isn't it ?

clear this confusion for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not confused. The access token can be abused if it is obtained by an unauthorised person for as long as the token is valid. The expiration date depends on the provider (e.g. Facebook, Twitter).

So it is important to secure this token at all times (SSL for transfer and some algorithm for persistence see also [Securely storing an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486090/securely-storing-an-access-token?rq=1))